# How to scan if Ubuntu is infected? server attack

Tags: security, malware

Sometimes I can not enter my website because according to the hosting administrator you tell me that from my IP or from my computer "attacks and port scanning are being launched to various servers protected by the Bitninja network."

How can I do an analysis or scan to my computer in Ubuntu to find out if there are any viruses?

Answer (score 3):

You could start with the following:

1. [clamav](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV)
2. [aide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FileIntegrityAIDE) - it's not a malware scanner but an integrity tool, meaning you can check what files were changed since say yesterday.
3. check open ports:

   ```
   sudo netstat -lpntu | less
   ```

If you have some wide open one, restrict them by IP for instance.

4. also check the running services to make sure you don't have anything suspicious:

   ```
   pstree | less

   ps axu | less
   ```
5. check cron tasks

Comment: AIDE: perfect tool. clamav not so.., it will scan linux files with rules that copied from windows. Never going to give a correct result

Answer (score 1):

Use ClamAV from Ubuntu see the instructions here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV

It is very strange to have any kind of malware on Ubuntu, but if any known viruses have been installed that should find it. However, I suspect that you do not use a static IP address and that the dynamically assigned IP address has been blocked prior to it being assigned to you. You should check and log your WAN IP address whenever you have the issue and when you don't for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Advice above looks good also.
Adding this >> How to determine if mysterious programs in ***nethogs*** listing are malware ?
[Are mysterious programs in ***nethogs*** listing malware ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91055/how-to-tell-if-mysterious-programs-in-nethogs-listing-are-malware)

Confirm nethogs info using netstat to NAME the calling Program

**`# netstat -tapec`**

**Active Internet connections (servers and established)**

**Proto, Recv-Q, Send-Q, Local Address, Foreign Address, State, User Inode,       PID/Program name**

root@-:~
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.55:46092          stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED        2360457     3618/firefox

tcp        0      0 192.168.0.55:60884          ec2-35-160-7-16.u:https ESTABLISHED        35667       3618/firefox