# Root privileges dangers

Tags: permissions, root

If I gain root privileges via executing "pkexec su" command, does this open the door to viruses on my laptop? Ubuntu 19.10 Thanks.

Comment: Running `pkexec su` should prompt for your password in a GUI window. That's quite a barrier for a random virus to overcome. If the virus already knows your password, then there are much easier ways for it to control your system.

Comment: I wouldn't loose sleep over it.

Answer (score 0):

Only until you close the windows where pkexec su is. Once that's closed, nothing you type could let in a virus.

Comment: Can you give an example of a virus you can catch using `sudo`? All I've read about is with `sudo apt-get` which is covered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/817993/can-i-get-a-virus-by-using-sudo-apt-get-install

Comment: Was trying to reassure OP that once they closed the su session, security risks were back to normal.