# I only have the Ubuntu Server. Can I install Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: server, repository, desktop-environments

Like it says above, I only have a server. Am I able to download the desktop version (preferably 16.01 LTS, if I'm remembering the right one) from a repository?

Comment: Just install the desktop on top of the server, no need to install a new desktop version unless you don't like the server version...

Comment: If you are running a server it may have security implications: you now have more code. Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/101829/why-is-x11-a-security-risk-in-servers.

Answer (score 1):

### If a server

If you want to run the computer as a server, you should not keep it busy with a desktop environment. I suggest that you try a **simple window manager**, for example **fluxbox** or **openbox**, that you can start when you need it and exit from it when you don't need it.

It is probably enough to **install three packages plus the application program(s)** that makes you want the graphic user interface,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install fluxbox xinit xterm
```

(Installing the packages will bring a lot of 'necessary packages', but much less than a full desktop environment).

You can start the window manager with the following command

```
startx
```

and manage it via right-clicking to get menus (where you can also exit from the window manager and return to the text screen).

### Else (if not a server)

If you do not want to run the computer as a server, it is probably a good idea to make a fresh installation of standard Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS or one of the Ubuntu family desktop flavours,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)